# yum list installed: Out of memory allocating

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

Имеется fedora 25 с 4ГБ ОЗУ. 
При выполнении команды  `#yum list installed`  или `yum list installed > text` получаю

> Out of memory allocating 4294967296 bytes!

4294967296 bytes == 4Гб

На момент выполнения команды в системе доступно более 3Гб свободной ОЗУ.
Swap свободен 500Мб

В системном журнале:

> [79678.056028] Out of memory: Kill process 16669 (dnf) score 548 or
>   sacrifice child [79678.056032] Killed process 16669 (dnf)
>   total-vm:6713724kB, anon-rss:3627656kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Куда копать? по какой причине 4Гб не хватает? как решить проблему?

Comment: так вроде уже давно переехали на dnf (с 18-22 версии), а yum просто обертка вокруг него. Так как его похоже никто не поддерживает... то и получаете.

Comment: да, но yum перенаправляет на dnf. в итоге выполняется команда `dnf list installed`, которая также отжирает память

Comment: @0andriy как вы это поняли?

Comment: @0andriy оформите как ответ, пожалуйста. нужно удалить весь кэш.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Количество байт выделяемой памяти является круглым числом, что наводит на мысль либо об ошибке в программе, либо о некачественной проверке входных данных. Входными данными являются также и временно сохранённые файлы -- кэш. На просторах интернета предлагают удалить данные (*.solv* файлы) из каталога */var/cache/*. В некоторых случаях можно попробовать удалить весь кэш `dnf`, `PackageKit`, находящийся там ([есть некий отчёт об ошибке про это](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80053)).

Ну и пища для размышлений: [статья годичной давности про `dnf`](https://lwn.net/Articles/702629/)

Comment: мне помогло удаление всего кэша